# Prevent response in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot to make a mock of one of our more complicated services. While all of the standard cases are easily done there is one that is causing me some troubles. It is theoretically possible for the application I am mocking to crash and close the connection without sending a response.

I tried several things to achieve this in spring boot without actually having my mock to crash. This includes throwing exceptions that go into an exception handler and from there do not properly response, however so far that either has generated an error response by spring or somehow resolved to an empty response.

Is there an option to have a method in a `@Conroller` to cause a closed connection without any response?

Answer (score 1):

Closing the connection is the responsibility of HTTP specification and protocol. You cannot enforce it programmatically. Connection negotitation is happening between HTTP Client and HTTP Server.

Although you can try interrupting current Thread or setting header **Connection: close**, but you should not be messing around with that part of the processing of a Connection and Request. Your HTTP server can start behaving unexpectedly.

Try a different approach. If you need to simulate a closed connection you can programmatically allocate a new instance of HTTP server, send a request to it, put request processing on hold and kill an instance is a separate thread. I'm sure you'll find a better way for this, just get to the root of the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/your-url")
public String test() {
    return null;
}
```

you can also change @Controller to @RestController and remove the @ResponseBody

Comment: Ah, I think my title made my question a bit ambiguous. With response I meant the entire HTTP response. Ideally the client should get a `connection closed` without any content being sent to the client. With a `null` response it will get a valid 200 OK response with just 0 content.

Comment: Maybe some hard: try to put in controller: Thread.currentThread().interrupt();